# iAd restarts game when it pops up

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

When you start my app It will run normally then all of a sudden when the iAd banner pops it restarts the game it will go back to the title screen restarting all progress:

this is my ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

and this is the ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MyScene.h"
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
@interface ViewController () <ADBannerViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,strong) ADBannerView *banner;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (banner.isBannerLoaded) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
        // Assumes the banner view is placed at the bottom of the screen.
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    if (!banner.isBannerLoaded) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
        // Assumes the banner view is just off the bottom of the screen.
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = NO;
    skView.showsNodeCount = NO;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;



    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];


}

- (void) viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    self.banner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.banner.delegate = self;
    [self.banner sizeToFit];
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;

    SKView *view = (SKView *)self.originalContentView;
    SKScene *scene = [[MyScene alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    [view presentScene:scene];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you narrow the code down to a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 3):

I would assume `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is being called again when the iAd view comes up.

Put an NSLog there to verify it.  If so, try moving everything inside it to `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` instead.

Comment: This is likely since I believe it gets called when there are changes to the view dimensions - which I believe happens when the banner created.

Comment: it's definitely the problem as accounted by numerous similar questions/issues